# PHP replace character in file without open file

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, file-writing

I have a file, that contain:
`file content NULNULNULNUL something else`.
When I try get file content
`$str = file_get_contents($fileName)`, in `$str` appear just `file content`.
How I can replace the NUL in file, without open file?

Comment: How can I get my chocolate out of my fridge without opening it?! (<- If you are able to answer this you can also answer your own question)

Comment: Ok, how I can get the data, if in the middle of the file I have NUL?

Comment: It should work fine. `file_get_contents()` reads a file into a string. So you would have to show us your **full** and **real** code. Show us what the current output is and what you would expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

1.) To get the replaced content as a string. First get the file content just like you did.

```
$str = file_get_contents($fileName)
```

Then replace all occurances of `NUL` with a blank space like:

```
$new_content =  str_replace('NUL'," ",$str);
```

**OR**

2.) To replace the content inside the file (to replace content and write it back to the file):

```
file_put_contents($fileName,str_replace('NUL',' ',file_get_contents($fileName)));
```

here we are using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)  — which writes a string to a file. We pass the `filename` and the `replaced-string` as a parameter

Answer (score -1):

I convert each character to assci code. This is work now:

```
$newStr='';
$str = file_get_contents($fileName);
$length = strlen($str);

for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $current = ord($str{$i});
    if ($current != 0x0)
    {
        $newStr .= chr($current);
    }
    else
    {
        $newStr .= "";
    }
}
$num = file_put_contents($fileName,$newStr);
```